# Android gradlew.bat assembleRelease choose starting package

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.3

I have an Android Studio App that now has close to 100 "productFlavors" associated with it, of course all defined in the `build.gradle`. I would like to build them from command line since building them one at a time in the IDE would be a nightmare. My issue arises when I run into an error in the middle of building them using the command line `gradlew.bat assembleRelease`. Once I fix the error I would like to start building at the point of failure (maybe 50 flavors into the build) rather than at the beginning. Is there a way to do that with Gradle? With Ant I was forced to comment them out, I am hoping there is a better way with Gradle since the structure is much more complicated in the file.

**UPDATE**

I finally went with a solution that encompassed Gradle and Ant (yucky but it works). Basically I wanted to build on of my 100 White Label flavors, with a prefix of the version, and then copy it to the deliver APK without the version. To do this my ANT script looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
DEPLOY_DIR=C:/AndroidBuilds/MyCompany.Build
VERSION="63"

NAME="WhiteLabel1"
DEPLOY_FOLDER="whitelabel1"
APK_NAME=$NAME$".apk"
gradlew assemble$NAME
cp $DEPLOY_DIR/$DEPLOY_FOLDER/$VERSION"-"$APK_NAME $DEPLOY_DIR/$DEPLOY_FOLDER/$APK_NAME

NAME="WhiteLabel2"
DEPLOY_FOLDER="whitelabel2"
APK_NAME=$NAME$".apk"
gradlew assemble$NAME
cp $DEPLOY_DIR/$DEPLOY_FOLDER/$VERSION"-"$APK_NAME $DEPLOY_DIR/$DEPLOY_FOLDER/$APK_NAME
```

This results in 2 APKs being generated, `63-WhiteLabel1.APK` and `63-WhiteLabel2.APK`, which are then copied to their respective deploy directories as `WhiteLabel1.APK` and `WhiteLabel2.APK`

I suppose if you are clever you could make this take parameters to run just the one you want, but Android Studio does a pretty decent job of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specifically do that, but you can work around the issue and fix it with some script-magic.

If you have a build type called `Release`, and a flavor called `Iron`, you could run:

```
gradlew.bat assembleIronRelease
```

So you could write a script that would run through a loop of all flavors, and if it fails, it would tell you which one failed. You can then fix the error, and start the script again, telling it to start at X flavor (you would have to write the logic to tell it where to start though).

Comment: Would that be a Gradle script or some other type of script?

Comment: Use I could write an Ant script which triggers the Gradle script with all my flavors listed as above, with logic for failure?

Comment: I eventually went with an Ant script that did several things in addition to the gradle build.